# jquery - dot indication works only one way

Tags: jquery

I want to have four dots that indicate what page you are on. I have finally got it to work but only one way. When i start and change the page to the right it works, but when i change the direction all of the dots get the class activePage. 
I guess that it's my function that could have been done in a different way to solve that problem.

```js
function activePage() {
  if (currentPage <= 2) {
    $(".one").addClass("activePage");
  } else if (currentPage == 3) {
    $(".one").removeClass("activePage");
    $(".two").addClass("activePage");
  } else if (currentPage == 4) {
    $(".two").removeClass("activePage");
    $(".three").addClass("activePage");
  } else {
    $(".three").removeClass("activePage");
    $(".four").addClass("activePage");
  }
};

// ########################################
// function to show arrow to the LEFT
// ########################################
$(".back").on("click", function() {
  currentPage -= 1;
  activePage();
  $(".page").hide();
  $('.page-' + currentPage).fadeIn(1000);
  if (currentPage == 1) {
    $(".back").hide();
  }
  if (currentPage > 1) {
    $(".back").show();
  }
  if (currentPage == lastPage - 1) {
    $(".next").show();
  }
}).hover(arrowHover, arrowHoverOut);


// ########################################
// function to show arrow to the RIGHT 
// ########################################
$(".next").on("click", function() {
  currentPage += 1;
  activePage();
  $(".page").hide();
  $(".page-" + currentPage).fadeIn(1000);
  $(".back").show();
  if (currentPage == lastPage) {
    $(".next").hide();
  }
}).hover(arrowHover, arrowHoverOut);
```

```css
#navigator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navigator .circle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8.5px;
  height: 8.5px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #707173;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#navigator .circle {
  background: lightgray;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#navigator .circle.activePage {
  background: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigator">
  <div class="circle one">1</div>
  <div class="circle two">2</div>
  <div class="circle three">3</div>
  <div class="circle four">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve like below:-

```
function activePage() {
    $('#navigator div').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all div first
    if(currentPage <= 2) {
        $(".one").addClass("activePage");
    } else if (currentPage == 3 ){
        $(".two").addClass("activePage");
    } else if (currentPage == 4) {
        $(".three").addClass("activePage");
    } else {
        $(".four").addClass("activePage");
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! :D Works great!